# Do RabbitMQ, Beanstalk or Resque support scheduling a task at a certain date?

Tags: rabbitmq, resque, mq, beanstalkd

I've looked at **RabbitMQ**, **Beanstalk** and **Resque**, which all seem geared towards asynchronous, non-delayed tasks (i.e., run all of these as quickly as possible).

Do any of them support scheduling a task **on a certain timestamp**?

Answer (score 1):

Beanstalk has provisions for a "delay" parameter whereby you can delay the message on a delay queue for a specific period of time.

Resque has one or more scheduling add-ons to it that will provide for scheduling tasks.

With queues, the delay is often an integer specifying the number of seconds to delay (in which case you'll need to convert to the delta you need). More robust scheduling -- as part of a task queue for example -- will often take datetime values via a client library.

Note that you can also use IronMQ push queues (with a delay like beanstalk) or IronWorker (scheduling a task instead of queuing it). (Note that I work for Iron.io.)

Answer (score 0):

Deplayed_job does this:

```
Delayed::Job.enqueue(MailingJob.new(params[:id]), 3, 3.days.from_now)
```

http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job?view=asciicast